# Unable to install DroidCam in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation, compiling, droidcam

Terminal prompt is as follows:

```
arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:~$ gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`

Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gcc

arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:~$ 
arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:~$ sudo apt install gcc
[sudo] password for arunava: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-7 libasan4 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libgcc-7-dev
  libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc ............
..................
  arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:/tmp$ # OK?
arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:/tmp$ unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam && cd droidcam
Archive:  droidcam_latest.zip
  inflating: droidcam/LICENCE        
  inflating: droidcam/Makefile       
  inflating: droidcam/README.md      
  inflating: droidcam/droidcam       
  inflating: droidcam/droidcam-cli   
  inflating: droidcam/install        
   creating: droidcam/src/
  inflating: droidcam/uninstall      
   creating: droidcam/v4l2loopback/
  inflating: droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c  
  inflating: droidcam/v4l2loopback/Makefile  
  inflating: droidcam/v4l2loopback/test-mmap.c  
  inflating: droidcam/v4l2loopback/test.c  
arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:/tmp/droidcam$ sudo ./install
Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
./install: line 36: make: command not found
arunava@arunava-H110M-S2:/tmp/droidcam$
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install build-essential make
cd /tmp/droidcam/
sudo ./install
```